# Accessing final array after fetching from Firebase in Swift

Tags: arrays, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to fetch relational data from firebase in swift 3 and storing it in an array. It does fetch everything the way I want it to but i can't access the final array to work with.
I have tried everything I found online but can't make it work properly.

There are 3 child nodes I'm fetching, so every time it fetches it appends it to the array.

The output is:

```
success
success
success
```

I just want it to print "success" once.

Here is my code:

```
// Here the child with the relations is loaded
func fetchFollowingSection1IDs() {
    guard let userID = FIRAuth.auth()?.currentUser?.uid else { return }

    let reference = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("interests").child("relations").child("userAndSection1").child(userID)
    reference.observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        // It's supposed to fetch the details of Section1 according to the childs from the relations (they are the IDs of Section1)
        self.fetchSection1(section1ID: snapshot.key, completionHandler: { success in
            guard success == true else {
                return
            }

            print("success")
            self.collectionView?.reloadData()

        })

    }, withCancel: nil)
}

// Here it gets the details from Firebase
func fetchSection1(section1ID: String, completionHandler: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {

    let ref = FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("interests").child("details").child("country").child("section1").child(section1ID)
    ref.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

        self.collectionView?.refreshControl?.endRefreshing()

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            let section1 = Section1New(section1ID: section1ID, dictionary: dictionary)
            self.section1s.append(section1)
        }

        completionHandler(true)

    }) { (err) in
        print("Failed to fetch section1s:", err)
    }   
}
```

My Firebase structure for the relations looks like this:

```
"interests" : {
    "relations" : {
      "userAndSection1" : {
         "7fQvYMAO4yeVbb5gq1kEPTdR3XI3" : { // this is the user ID
            "-KjS8r7Pbf6V2f0D1V9r" : true,  // these are the IDs for Section1
            "-KjS8tQdJbnZ7cXsNPm3" : true,
            "-KjS8unhAoqOcfJB2IXh" : true
    },
}
```

Everything loads properly and populates my collection views. It is just the problem that it is the wrong number of Section1s because of the triple appending to the array.

Thank you for your answers!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code is doing exactly what you are telling it to do.

Your firebase event is .childAdded so it will iterate over each child node one at a time.

It first loads -KjS8r7Pbf6V2f0D1V9r and adds it to the section1s array - there is then one item in the array.

Then it loads -KjS8tQdJbnZ7cXsNPm3 and appends to the array. There's two items in the array and two lines output. etc.

The only thing we don't see in the code in your question is the line that actually prints the array, which is probably in your collectionView delegate methods.

Depending on your use case, you may want to read everything in with .value, and then iterate over that to populate your dataSource array.

Comment: Thank you! I found the solution for my problem after realizing, this is just not the right code for my needs! Nevertheless it works and may help someone with a similar problem :)